# Ajax calls within the changing Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i am working on my first Ajax Project and i cannot find a solution for this problem:

This is my Ajax Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var seite = $('div.ipadSeite');

$('a').on('click', function(e){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    seite.load( href );
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

});

And this is the index.php:

```
....<div id="ipadHeader">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>100% |=|</li>
                <li>
                    <?php 
                        echo date("h:i a");
                    ?> 
                </li>
                <li>TWT</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="ipadSeite">
        <img src="../images/homescreen.png" id="homescreenImage" />
        <a href="seiten/1app.php"><div id="appIcon"><p>TWT</p></div></a>
    </div>
</div>....
```

When first starting the Application the Link: a href="seiten/1app.php is working! So I created an Home Button to go Back to the index.php. This is the File wich is loaded trough Ajax to go back "home":

```
    <img src="../images/homescreen.png" id="homescreenImage" />
<a href="informationen.php"><div id="appIcon"><p>TWT</p></div></a>
```

It simply loads the same content in "ipadSeite". 
My first Question: This is wrong right? It should be easier? But when linking to index.php it loads the whole site (header, footer ..) and the functionality breaks.

Second Question: My Solution works, but when i click on the button another time, it dont makes an Ajax Request. Instead it opens a regular link but without CSS. I really cannot find any solution for that. I hope you guys understand my problem and my explanation.

Thank you very much! 
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate function:

```
$(document).delegate('a','click',function(){//Write your function here})
```

'On' I find very situational. 'Delegate' and 'live' both work well with asynchronously load elements.

Robert

Comment: Its working! Thank you Robert! :) But why does delegate work better than on? I thought "delegate" would refer to "on" in jQuery Source?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from a cursory glance you are not using AJAX but simply utilising jQuery's functions.

What exactly are you trying to do? If you lay out a point by point run through of what a user journey is then I am sure someone can help you.

Robert

[Edit]

have you tried accessing a specific section on the homepage:

```
<script>
  $("#new-nav").load("/ #jq-footerNavigation li");
</script>
```

The above code says get some data from homepage '/' and load it into the '#new-nav' element

In your case it should be .load('/ .ipadSeite' )

Comment: i've got an ipad on index. Above the iPad is my navigation.
A user is now able to click a link in the navigation and the "website" displayed on the ipad should chance through ajax (of course you`re right, i am using just the jquery function) I build it and its working fine, the only problem i've got, is that a link which can be clicked from within! the ipad does not work asynchronously, instead it opens .../help.com in the same tab.

Comment: Rather than on I prefer to use delegate()

Answer (score 0):

First I think you reference the div by class while you have it in id

var seite = $('div.ipadSeite');   => var seite = $('#ipadSeite');

Comment: Hey Zero, i have also referenced it by class. Did you mean the "<div id="ipadHeader">" in first line?